# Hololens + Unity: GameObjects are invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

After I build my Unity project and send it to the Hololens, I have the following problem:
The splash screen appear followed by a debugging window on the bottom. In the background is a white net. However, you can't see any game objects. I've tested a lot but haven't found a solution for that. Visual Studio does not display any error messages. What I've looked at roughly:

[These are my modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nix7w.png). Im using the 2019.4.22f1 version of Unity and the MRTK Foundation Toolkit 2.7.2.

[My build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g07x.png)

[My project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEy3C.png)

I tried to place the objects in the middle of the camera and changed the colors.

[MRTK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIilH.png) I haven't changed anything most of the time

[Main camera settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sLYt.png)

[My scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgTWo.png)

[When i start the scene i get this error in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZebBN.png) I dont know if this has anything to do with my problem

Answer (score 0):

### i have two possible solutions (no guarantee)##

1. you could spawn the objects on input directly in front of the
   camera, add a debug.log("object in front of you"); so you can find
   the issue.
2. If this doesnt work i would try to test differnet types of materials
   like you do with HDRP.

if this does not work either i probably cant help you out now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your GameObject is too far to be hidden behind by the mesh. Please make the spatial mesh invisible by setting the Display Option property of Spatial Mesh Observer Setting to None, this item can be found under the Spatial Awareness profile of the MRTK profile.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Does it work in the Unity editor when you click the play button? We want to know if the gameobject is within the view of the camera.

Comment: This first problem was the camera indeed.

Comment: But the Gameobjects are still invisible. I found out that I can see them when I cover the cameras of the Hololens. When I turn off Spatial Awareness by the inspektor nothing happened.

Comment: I found that the Projection property of your Camera has been set to Orthographic, but we generally set it to Perspective. Could you fix it and try again?